# Magento Checkout final step Error --- "Falied to connect : 0"

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.0.1

After patch the 6788 to the magento store(CE,Ver1.9.0.1),At the final stage of checkout(url /checkout/onepage/success/), it always display an error message of "Failed to connect: 0". Even revert that patch can't resolve the problem.Also failed on back to the backup former version or even uninstall all extra extensions. But everything is fine while pull the code to the local stage, Any clue or idea will be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: My assumption would be that the site can't connect to the payment gateway based on being in the final step.  Are orders going through?   

I would download the entire site if you haven't already, and use something to search the entire site for the words "Failed to connect" (I assume the misspelling in Failed is yours, if the error is misspelled it should be easier to track down). 

My site has this term quite a few times, but it is always followed by "Failed to connect to FTP" or something similar.   Seeing what module has that error can help you track down what is failing to connect.

Comment: Thanks TJ, The order did go through normally while the error message continues, searched all the source files for that "Failed to connect" message, only get the FTP related occurrence as you said, which seems not so relevant with my error.Anyway ,thanks again.